# Using multiple google drive accounts to get around the 15Gb limit

Tags: gmail, google-drive, chromebook

I'm too scared I'll get on Google's trap list if I ask this question in one of their forums (I know I'm just being paranoid, but still) which is why I'm asking the question here.

Google drive is cheap enough that its not worth the inconvenience, BUT I'm still curious if the following would get you into trouble:

I have an email: MyEmail@gmail.com

Then I create a bunch more accounts to get that sweet sweet free google drive storage:
MyEmailEbooks@gmail.com
MyEmailMovies@gmail.com
MyEmailMusic@gmail.com

I use the google drive account for those emails to save various data.

Pretty sure this is not cool with google is it?

It may seem silly to do, but you can use 3rd party apps (grive) that access google's API to sync multiple accounts on the same machine which means I could have a top level folder "Drive" and then sub-folders Ebooks, Music, Movies and sync those folders up with the other drive accounts. It would be awfully inconvenient from other platforms like my android phone, but while I'm on my  desktop it would be fairly seamless.

EDIT: I just thought of a scenario when I would consider this. If you buy a chrome book you get 100Gb of drive storage. If you buy another chrome book you can only redeem another 100Gbs with a different drive account. So if down the road I start buying mucho chromebooks I may spawn additional drive accounts.

EDIT2: Sorry, but I can't stop thinking of ways to game the system now. What if you had a program that represented itself to the OS as a single folder but when you drop files in it they are evenly distributed to sub-folders, each of which is hooked up to its own drive account. I suppose I should assume that's illegal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is some sort of license agreement for Google Drive which will answer your question about the legality of your endeavour.

I think the big issue is that it's not supported out of the box. The original Google Drive tool will not support you on doing that, and neither will you be able to access your drives on other devices such as your phone or tablet without messing with the settings all the time.

And, let's face it, current third party tools just aren't nearly as good and complete as Google's original.

So, yes, technically you can get more space but you lose much of the convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Different people in the same house with different google accounts can share the same computer, logging in at **different times**, I don't think there's anything wrong with that. Maybe one of them only likes movies and the other only likes music, who knows.

But if the different people were all signed in at the **same time** and syncing all their storage **together**, that would probably raise some **red flags** at google, especially if they all shared the same first part of their email/login names, and ended it with "Movies" or "Music".

---

I think just paying for more online storage would be a lot cheaper & easier than buying an armfull of chromebooks.

[image]