# Owning multiple Google drive accounts for cloud storage

Tags: google-drive, google-accounts

**Disclaimer**: I have been searching this and other sites for previous answers, and always find questions/answers related to **syncing** multiple accounts **to a PC** via the Google Drive software. My concern is simply about **sharing** files between different accounts without bringing the PC into consideration - only as a form of cloud backup.

The closest post I have found is [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1000526/using-multiple-google-drive-accounts-to-get-around-the-15gb-limit), but while it formulates my question pretty well, the answers given still revolve around syncing to a PC and the use of the Drive software, and how it can be abusive to have simultaneous Google accounts syncing at once from one PC.

---

**Problem**: What I would like to know is whether I can own several google accounts which all share their storage Drives with one central account, and whether this is considered "abusing" the system. After all, shared folders only use up the storage quota of the original folder owner. Namely, any personal experiences from anyone with a similar setup would be very useful.

I'm not asking just out of nitpickery, I'm legitimately interested (read "paranoid") about a secondary form of backing up a large-ish amount of information - say around 150 GB, 10 times the quota for free accounts -
 other than physical drives (which would be my primary form of backup).

As for why bother having multiple Google accounts instead of just paying for upgraded storage for one account, consider the remote possibility of losing access to said account - by spreading the ownership of data among several accounts, there would be a marginally lower chance of losing everything. Plus, if all accounts share data among themselves, **any** particular one can access everything at once.

Note how this method does not require simultaneous logins, nor does it put a strain on file syncing, therefore in theory it should not be considered abusive.

Comment: If you just want infinite storage and don't care about hassle, use the Telegram messenger. You are limited to 1500000000 Bytes (a little under 1.5GB) per file, but you can upload as many as you want. If you are unsure about if it's allowed and don't want to rely on my word for it, ask the official support from inside the program. I uploaded multiple TB in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Often times questions like this one are very opinionated and open to subjectivity; albeit, it can be approached objectively through pragmatism. Your question focuses on Google Drive, so I shall not bother with other online backup alternatives. I am not responsible for your loss of data or security issues if you follow my suggestion, it is up to you to make up your mind on what is best to you, this is entirely a suggestion. I'm not affiliated with Google and as such unfamiliar with their terms and policies to a perfect extent, it is up to you the consumer to know their terms and policies, even if I portray them badly.

I believe dealing with multiple accounts by divvying up the storage load, is too much of hassle in managing a filesystem to direct multiple storage allocations to different accounts, which would actually be against Gmail's Terms of Use (see below) as abuse - this may cross apply to any and all Google Accounts. It's also a hassle managing different accounts and passwords, so I don't believe that would be very fun at all and would not be very practical.

Perhaps you can do the upgraded storage for a single account, but share all files and folders with secondary accounts of yours (perhaps 1 or 3 accounts max), such that if you lose the primary account you can at least access all your files and download them. However, if you choose this you have more doorways into your file folders which creates a security risk (so perhaps on non-primary accounts you would set it to read or view only so they can still be downloaded but kept unchanged and non-deleted).

In my opinion, the chances of losing access to a Google account is very minimal, if you have sufficient security precautions. For your Google account with an upgraded, you should have two-step authentication (for security purposes) and you should link the account with multiple backup emails (ones you trust) and multiple phone numbers (again ones you trust). As long as you have access, you should be able to change these phone numbers and email addresses; so whenever, you expect a change to these, change them before they become unavailable to regain access. With such precautions, I doubt that your account will become unrecoverable or inaccessible.

Since you claim it is most or about 150GB, it may be wise to have another local backup - just as another safety step, because that is relatively small.

---

From [Google's Purchase, cancellation, & refund policies](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2736362?hl=en)

> If you use Gmail and the auto-renewal fails, your storage plan will be
> extended for seven days and you'll have seven days to update your
> payment information. You can use those extra seven days to clear space
> in your account or buy a new storage plan.
>
> **If your storage plan is canceled or expires**
>
> If you cancel your storage
> plan or when your storage plan expires, your storage limits will reset
> to the free levels for each product at the end of your billing cycle.
> Everything in Google Drive, Google Photos, and Gmail will still be
> accessible, but you won't be able to create or add anything new over
> the free storage limit. If you reach or exceed the free storage limit:
>
> Google Drive: You won't be able to sync or upload new files, and
> syncing between your Google Drive folder and My Drive will stop.
> You'll still be able to create Google documents since they don't take
> up any storage space.
>
> Google Photos: You'll only be able to upload new
> photos and videos stored at High quality.
>
> Gmail: Incoming messages to
> your account will be returned to the sender.

I would assume there would be a time-limit to this before they are like "You have 300TB and you have the free plan after years of expiration." They would probably hold the right to delete the storage (though I can't find the policy), which then they would likely try to have you pay (or maybe not) for a window of time to download all your data before they delete it all.

From [Google's Gmail Policies](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/policy/) (It says "Gmail Account" which is likely synonymous with "Google Account" thus "Gmail account limitations" are "Google account limitations") answering your question about abuse (while not explicit if this applies to Google Drive) - **do not do it!**:

> **The Creation and Use of Multiple Gmail Accounts**
>
> Don’t create or use multiple accounts to abuse Google policies, bypass
> Gmail account limitations, circumvent filters, or otherwise subvert
> restrictions placed on your account

From [Google's Inactive Account Manager settings](https://myaccount.google.com/inactive) (as of this writing) you have many options *if* you set it:

1. You choose when your account becomes inactive (unused, not-logged-in): 3, 6, 12, 18 months.
2. Who obtains access to said information if inactive for that period of time (if one wishes).
3. What happens to said account content when it becomes inactive: Delete entire account, or don't - just becomes inactive.

If these are not set the default is nine months (or so it used to be, I can't find the policy on it anymore). If your account does become inactive, Google seemingly claims they hold the right to terminate and do whatever with (which I'd assume is synonymous with delete) your account and all its contents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question does indeed focus on Google Drive as my concern is whether these accounts might be deactivated on the basis of Google's own usage policies, which are not exhaustively explicit on this subject.

The data itself is not truly sensitive so security is a secondary issue, it is more of a risk-minimization strategy. About the hassle, it can be somewhat annoying but with proper organization it also becomes a secondary matter, as once the accounts share data with each other, ideally only one account is used to subsequently retrieve data.

Comment: I have also considered a secondary physical backup, but it would have to be stored independently from the primary one, as it would otherwise be subject to the same (low) risk of (unlikely) loss - theft, fire, etc... And I have no secondary physical location available.

Comment: So multiple identities, and you will be telling the truth for all of them?